# Does java's fileWriter() function works for Linux type machines?

Tags: java, windows, linux

I am using java fileWriter() function. It works on Windows machine but not in Linux.

So I want to know if fileWriter() function works only on Windows or there is another problem?

Thanks in advance
Enamul

Comment: Java is multiplatform. And FileWriter is a class, not a function. Why don't you share your code, and tell us what the problem is?

Comment: Also, just saying Linux really isn't enough. You should really specify ubuntu, redhat etc

Answer (score 8):

I have seen similar reports of people saying file IO is not working on Linux for them. The problem almost always ended up being they were using Windows' directory path separators.

```
String filePath = "my\\file\\path\\File.txt"; // only works on windows
String filePath = "my/file/path/File.txt"; // works on all platforms
```

Make sure you are using the latter, they even work on Windows (from within Java at least)!

Comment: Thanks Jesse Webb, that's the problem I was facing.

Comment: @EnamulHaque - If my answer helped you solve your problem, you should click the little check mark to the left of my answer to "accept" it as the correct one. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to the FileWriter class?  If so it behaves on both systems correctly, if not, you will have to tell us where the fileWriter() function is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The FileWriter class functions for both systems, but bear in mind that Linux and Windows use different path conventions - UNIX-based systems use a forward slash '/' to separate directories and fiels, and Windows uses a backslash '\' to separate them.  So if you have a file named 'file.txt' in a directory labeled 'home', it will be /home/file.txt in Linux, and C:\home\file.txt in Windows, because you will most likely be in the C: drive on Windows.

However, the File class, which you will almost certainly need to make a FileWriter has four static fields - separatorChar, pathSeparatorChar, separator, and pathSeparator - which are determined by the system you're running on.  pathSeparator is "/" on Linux, for example, and "\" on Windows.  Refer to these fields (you don't even need to instantiate an object of type File - you can just use File.separatorChar, because the field is static) if you need to make a path to a file in either system.